# How to get attribute from Xpath

Tags: xpath

```
This is the XML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This file is generated by the program.-->
<DATABASE>
  <SCENE SCENE_NAME="SCENE_Winner">
    <TEMPLATE_template1>
      <ID_000-TEAM-REF-NAME>teamName1</ID_000-TEAM-REF-NAME>
      <ID_001-INFO>TeamInfo1</ID_001-INFO>
    </TEMPLATE_template1>
    <TEMPLATE_template2>
      <ID_000-TEAM-REF-NAME>teamName2</ID_000-TEAM-REF-NAME>
      <ID_001-INFO>TeamInfo2</ID_001-INFO>
    </TEMPLATE_template2>
    <TEMPLATE_template3>
      <ID_000-TEAM-REF-NAME>teamName3</ID_000-TEAM-REF-NAME>
      <ID_001-INFO>TeamInfo3</ID_001-INFO>
    </TEMPLATE_template3>
  </SCENE>
</DATABASE>
```

I am not very experienced with Xpath , how can i get all the Template names under the SCENE "SCENE_NAME="SCENE_Winner" element.

Also how can I get all the  attributes inside a particular template.

This is the xPath i am using but it does not gives the elements inside the SCENE_Winner

"/DATABASE/SCENE[@SCENE_NAME=" + "'" + "SCENE_"  + Winner + "']"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i am able to get all the elements inside the SCENE

```
    "/DATABASE/SCENE[@SCENE_NAME=" + "'" + "SCENE_" + Winner + "']/*"
```